# Closure does not capture variable

Tags: environment, lexical-scoping

I wrote the following code, but it does not work:

```lisp
(progn
  (define-prefix-command 'unicode-shortcut-keymap)
  (dolist (mapping '(("- >" . "→")))
    (let ((keys (car mapping))
          (text (cdr mapping)))
      (message text)
      (define-key unicode-shortcut-keymap (kbd keys)
        (lambda () (interactive) (insert text)))))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c u") 'unicode-shortcut-keymap))
```

When I try to use it, I get the error:

> Symbol’s value as variable is void: text

But `text` is not void, `message` displays the text.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *don't* have a closure unless your file has set `lexical-binding: t` as a file-local variable.

Without that, everything is using dynamic binding (in which case in your example your variable is indeed bound while your function is *defined* but is *not* still bound later on, when that function is *called*).

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Converting to Lexical Binding`

Comment: Is it safe to enable lexical binding in the `.emacs` file?

Comment: No one can tell you that.  Your init file is an elisp file like any other, and the code in that file must be considered.  It's not *unusual* to be able to make this change without needing to make other changes, but you need to read the documentation I pointed to to understand what changes *might* be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```lisp
(defmacro lexical (exp &rest exps)
  "Evaluate expressions with lexical scope."
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(eval '((lambda () ,exp ,@exps)) t))

(lexical
  (define-prefix-command 'unicode-shortcut-keymap)
  (dolist (mapping '(("- >" . "→")))
    (let ((keys (kbd (car mapping)))
      (insert-text (lambda () (interactive) (insert (cdr mapping)))))
      (define-key unicode-shortcut-keymap keys insert-text)))
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c u") 'unicode-shortcut-keymap))
```